# Unable to refresh access token of paypal

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am getting invalid refresh token using this url `https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=A21AAINhl7...._p4r5fZe1LJw`

My params:

```
grant_type=refresh_token
refresh_token="A21AAINhl7...._p4r5fZe1LJw"
```

header:

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

basic auth 
clientid
client secret
```

output

```
{
"error_description": "Unable to refresh access token",
"error": "invalid_request",
"correlation_id": "c58cc1...b0c5a",
"information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#errors"
}
```

Or how can I get refresh token using paypal api? Refresh token value is expired access token I have set in this url so, is that right?

Comment: What type of request are you sending, and what headers do you send?

Comment: this is post request with that heder is content type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded  and

Comment: i have update my question with full request.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the access token? The question does not give any context.

If it's from [grant_type=client_credentials for API access](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/get-started/#curl) , simply request a new one. Those cannot be refreshed.

Otherwise, update your question with full request/response and Connect with PayPal button information for how you are obtaining the access token in the first place.

Comment: yes using " grant_type=client_credentials " i can able to get access token now i want to refresh that token so that i am going to call this api request where i am getting error.

Comment: As my answer states, do not refresh your access token. The identity API is not for this. Request another (new) access token as soon as you need one. They typically expire after 9 hours.

Comment: yes you are totally right that we can generate new token but my requirement is to get  refresh token using previous one ,so i want to know that how can we achieve that.i have update my question with full request too .

Comment: There is no way. Refreshing is for a different type of access token, and not applicable to your use case. As stated, you must request a new token. This is what all API integrations do. All of them.